# Databinding of MapControl Center property in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I'm developing a windows phone 8.1 (winRT) app with MVVM Light and a PCL which use a MapControl.
I'm having an issue with the binding of the MapControl Center property.
At the initialization of the app, the property is set in the ViewModel and the map is correctly centered.

However, when I update the value in the ViewModel, the map is not re-centered but if I bind the value to a textblock it's correctly updated.

XAML :

```
<Maps:MapControl BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black"
        x:Name="Map" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,45,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Height="595"  Width="400"
        ZoomLevel="10"
        LandmarksVisible = "False"
        TrafficFlowVisible = "False"
        PedestrianFeaturesVisible = "False"
        Center="{Binding Path=ViewStoreModel.CenterPosition, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource NormalizedAnchorPointConverter}}"
        MapServiceToken="{StaticResource MapServiceTokenString}">

            <Maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="MapIcons" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewStoreModel.ListStoreSearch}"  >
                <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="Temp" >
                        <StackPanel Tapped="Image_Tapped" x:Name="MyStack"  Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding store_position, Converter={StaticResource GeoPointConvertCenter}}">
                            <Image x:Name="PinsImage" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/map-pin-button.png" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </Maps:MapItemsControl>
        </Maps:MapControl>
```

Property of the ViewModel:

```
    public Location CenterPosition
        {
            get
            { 
                return _centerPosition;
            }
             set
            {
              Set(CenterPositionPropertyName, ref _centerPosition, value);
            }
        }

public class Location : ObservableObject
{
    public const string latitudePropertyName = "latitude";
    public const string longitudePropertyName = "longitude";
    private double _latitude;
    private double _longitude;
    public double latitude
    {
        get
        {
            return _latitude;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(latitudePropertyName, ref _latitude, value);
        }

    }
    public double longitude
    {
        get
        {
            return _longitude;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(longitudePropertyName, ref _longitude, value);
        }
    }
```

The property Center is a type Geopoint so I use a converter to convert it from the custom class Location.
Center is a dependency property so it should be bindable.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out there are some bugs in the MapControl.
The problem comes from the binding mode. OneWay seems to work like OneTime (only at init).
If I put TwoWay it works but the map is updating the ViewModel continuously.

As a workaround, I specified that we have to tell explicity when the XAML has to update the source.

Code:

```
<Maps:MapControl BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black"
        x:Name="Map" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,45,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Height="595"  Width="400"
        ZoomLevel="10"
        LandmarksVisible = "False"
        TrafficFlowVisible = "False"
        PedestrianFeaturesVisible = "False"
        Center="{Binding ViewStoreModel.CenterPosition, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, Converter={StaticResource NormalizedAnchorPointConverter}}"
        MapServiceToken="{StaticResource MapServiceTokenString}"
        >
```

Answer (score 1):

We're using a bit of a different approach.
We used the DataContext's `PropertyChanged` event - in the handler we're checking if `e.PropertyName` equals `CurrentLocation` and if it does, I'm calling `NearbySitesMap.SetView(currentLocation, ZoomLevel, NearbySitesMap.Heading);`.
This way, when CurrentLocation changes, the map gets a nice and smooth animation to the new location.

Comment: Works well.. Instead of propertychanged you can also do an attached property and bind the CurrentLocation using that...

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to remove "Path" property and bind it directly to your ViewModel?

```
<Maps:MapControl Center="{Binding ViewStoreModel.CenterPosition, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource NormalizedAnchorPointConverter}}"/>
```